# parse-server user.signUp() not creating a session

Tags: parse-server

Environment:

1. Node.js 7.2
2. parse-server 2.2.25

In our cloud code, we are having an issue with the Parse.User signup() call not creating a sessionToken for the user post call when we enabled the `PARSE_SERVER_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_DIRECT_ACCESS` option.

This works:

```js
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var user = new Parse.User();
user.set('username', form_data.userEmail);   
user.set('email', form_data.userEmail); 

user.signUp().then(function(user) {
  // Valid Session Token
  var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
});
```

Since we have to refactor all calls to `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` and pass it as an option, we set `PARSE_SERVER_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_DIRECT_ACCESS=1`, and refactored to this and now this fails:

```js
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set('username', form_data.userEmail);   
user.set('email', form_data.userEmail); 

user.signUp(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(user) {
  // sessionToken = undefined
  var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
});
```

Our thought was that maybe getSessionToken required the useMasterKey option as well, but it isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this to github as I thought it was a bug.  It's actually expected behavior.  See: [Github Discussion](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3152#issuecomment-264243978)

Our configuration is not the standard way Parse was used.  This is a Node.js web app that makes ajax calls to Cloud code.  The Cloud code makes Javascript API calls to Parse.  This means we have no Installation object or installationIds.

The solution since we couldn't automatically login with signUp is to call Parse.User.login in the signUp response.